# install printer but dont make it default printer (windows, nsis)

Tags: windows, nsis

I've written an installer that sets a NUL: port and installs a printer driver and then installs the printer. However, when I run it under an admin account, the printer is always set as the default printer.

How can I stop that from happening?

Here's the code that sets the printer:

```
ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\$DisplayName" "Name"

${If} ${Errors}
      ExecWait '$SYSDIR\rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /r "$PrinterPort" /b "$DisplayName" /z /Gw /f "$DriverPath" /m "$DriverModel"'
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a good answer for this. [This blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/06/29/how-to-add-printers-with-no-user-interactiion-on-windows-7-windows-server-2008.aspx) documents `/y` as the switch to set the default printer but I don't see a switch to prevent changes to the default printer. You could try `/-y` or `/y-` but I really doubt those are supported.

You can read the `Device` value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` to get the current default and then use `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "$SavedPrinterName"` to restore it when you are done but that is a bit of a hack and would only affect the current user.

If you are a hardware manufacturer you can probably ask Microsoft support for a official answer...

Comment: Well, it's about installing a virtual printer. I think your way should be enough because under a non-admin account, the default setting isnt changed and the current user needs to be admin in order to install everything, so I guess it's okay if it only works for the current user (i.e. the admin). Thanks a lot!